# Why cant I later add a value to my string variable through if-statements and run the output code in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to run the gradeStatus in the Console.WriteLine but I fail...
I've almost checked all posts to some extent relevant but none have resolved my problem, please guide?

```
Console.WriteLine("Type in grade to get stats!");
int gradeScore = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Grade Score: {0}", gradeScore);
bool isPassed;
if (gradeScore >= 50)
{
    isPassed = true;
}
else
{
    isPassed = false;
}

Console.WriteLine("Passed: {0}", isPassed);

string gradeStatus;

if(gradeScore == 50)
{
    gradeStatus = "Okay";
}
else if (gradeScore == 60)
{
    gradeStatus = "Good";
}
else if (gradeScore >= 70)
{
    if (gradeScore == 70)
    {
        gradeStatus = "Great";
    }
    else if (gradeScore == 80)
    {
        gradeStatus = "Great";
    }
}
else if (gradeScore == 90)
{
    gradeStatus = "Excellent";
}
else if (gradeScore == 100)
{
    gradeStatus = "Ace!";
}

Console.WriteLine("Grade Status: {0}", gradeStatus);
```

Comment: _but I fail_ does not describe your problem adequately. What exactly do you expect to happen and what does the code actually do?

Comment: **[How to use the built-in, awesome Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your if statements. What you are probably wanting is the below portion of code for your set of if else statements.

```
            if(gradeScore <= 50)
            {
            gradeStatus = "Okay";
            }
            else if (gradeScore <= 60)
            {
            gradeStatus = "Good";
            }
            else if (gradeScore <= 70)
            {
            gradeStatus = "Great";
            }
            else if (gradeScore <= 80)
            {
            gradeStatus = "Great";
            }
            else if (gradeScore <= 90)
            {
            gradeStatus = "Excellent";
            }
            else if (gradeScore <= 100)
            {
            gradeStatus = "Ace!";
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a problem like this one, it is often much easier to break the logic into a separate function. When you use a separate function, you can use [early return](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement) to [avoid else](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206816/clarification-of-avoid-if-else-advice). That makes the logic much more plain and easy to read, and less prone to error.

For example, you could write a function like this one:

```
static string GetGradeStatus(int score)
{
    if (score <= 50) return "Okay";
    if (score <= 60) return "Good";
    if (score <= 70) return "Great";
    if (score <= 80) return "Great";
    if (score <= 90) return "Excellent";
    return "Ace";
}
```

And modify your code to use it:

```
Console.WriteLine("Type in grade to get stats!");
int gradeScore = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Grade Score: {0}", gradeScore);

var isPassed = gradeScore > 50;
Console.WriteLine("Passed: {0}", isPassed);

var gradeStatus = GetGradeStatus(gradeScore);
Console.WriteLine("Grade Status: {0}", gradeStatus);
```

This is easier to read and makes it very plain if you've got a logic error (e.g. it is obvious that "Great" is used twice, which is what your existing code does).

I also made two other changes:

1. I changed `=` to `<=` since there is nothing preventing the user from entering a number that is not a multiple of 10. That was just a guess. You might need to tweak the logic to meet your requirements correctly.
2. I changed the `if/else` assignment of `isPassed` to a simple Boolean assignment, which is idiomatic for c# and easier to read once you get used to it.